# why output is null at select translate(' @',' ','') from dual; and why resulit is @ at select replace(' @',' ','') from dual;

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically  translate will change character to character and Replace string to string , and  here i have tried to remove spaces using translate to count the number words .

```
select translate('  @',' ','') from dual;

select replace('  @',' ','') from dual;

select ename , nvl(length(replace(TRANSLATE(upper(trim(ename)),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'' ','                           @ '),' ',''))+1,1) NOOFWORDs
from emp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Oracle has made many bizarre choices around null vs. empty string.

One of those has to do with TRANSLATE. TRANSLATE will return NULL if **any** of its arguments (including the last one) is NULL, no matter what the *logical* behavior should be.

So, to remove spaces (say) with TRANSLATE, you must add a character you do NOT want to be removed to both the second and the third argument. I added the lower-case letter z, but you could add anything (a dot, the digit 0, whatever - just make sure you add the same character at the beginning of both arguments)

```
... translate (input_string, 'z ', 'z')    ....
```

For example:

```
select translate('  @','z ','z') from dual;

TRANSLATE('@','Z','Z')
------------------------
@
```

Comment: can you explain more why replace function will not return null when any argument is null?

Comment: @Annapurna - only Oracle can explain that. As I said, they made some bizarre and inconsistent choices. At least, the behavior of both functions is documented.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> select translate('  @',' ','') from dual;
> ```

Returns `NULL` because in Oracle empty strings unfortunately yield `NULL`s. Therefore it's equivalent to

```
SELECT translate('  @', ' ', NULL)
       FROM dual;
```

and `translate()` returns `NULL` when an argument is null. Actually this is well documented in ["TRANSLATE"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm):

> [image]
>
> (...)
>
> You cannot use an empty string for `to_string` to remove all characters in `from_string` from the return value. Oracle Database interprets the empty string as null, and if this function has a null argument, then it returns null.

If you want to replace one character, use `replace()` as you already did. For a few but more than one characters you can nest the `replace()`s.

This however gets unhandy, when you want to replace quite a lot of characters. In such a situation, if the replacement character is only one character or the empty string [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) using a character class or alternates may come in handy.

For example

```
SELECT regexp_replace('a12b478c01', '[0-9]', '')
       FROM dual;
```

replaces all the digits so just `'abc'` remains and

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ABcc1233', 'c|3', '')
       FROM dual;
```

removes any `'3'` or `'c'` and results in `'AB12'`. In your very example

```
SELECT regexp_replace('  @', ' ', '')
       FROM dual;
```

would also work and give you `'@'`. Though in the simple case of your example a simple `replace()` is enough.

Comment: "For a few characters" one should **not** nest calls to `replace`. They should use `translate`, but do it carefully, taking into account the bizarre handling of NULL as the third argument. I showed how in my Reply, which was already posted when you wrote yours.